# Should I include the argument even though it is not needed

Tags: javascript

Which one is a better way to write codes ?

1st version:

```
let displayTodos = (item) => console.log('My todo list:', todo)
displayTodos()
```

2nd version

```
let displayTodos = () => console.log('My todo list:', todo)
displayTodos()
```

Both will give me the same result but which one is the accepted standard to write a simple function ?

Comment: Either one of these is fine. If you're going to add item, consider writing like this. let displayTodos = item =>, since there is only one argument.

Comment: Where is `todo` defined?

Comment: 2nd version is preferable. Why would you specify an argument that's not used? Is the function being passed as a callback to something else that passes an argument (which you're ignoring)?

Comment: Many IDEs/editors/linters will claim to remove unused parameters. So I would stick to the second version.

Comment: @Barmar still learning the rope of ES6 so trying to experiment with writing clean codes. Thanks for clearing that up

Comment: What does ES6 have to do with it? It's the same as between `function displayTodos ()` and `function displayTodos(item)`

Comment: This is my 2.5 week into learning Javascript journey, kindly excuse my lack of knowledge. Cheers